# RavenDB RQL to retrieve also related document

Tags: ravendb

I'm using RavenDB 5.1

I have a parent document

```
{
   "ddt": "1313",
   "operator": "Dadas",
   "insertAt": "01/02/2021 12:15:47",
   "code": "R2021.001",
   "clientId": "cbaa9024-abf8-4575-8f44-c06bbb3d8a2e",
   "@metadata": {
      "@collection": "repairOrders"
   }
}
```

and other documents in another collection

```
{
   "name": "AZM2E",
   "piva": "31137418148",
   "@metadata": {
      "@collection": "clients"
   }
}
```

with RQL, I need a query that gives me:

```
{
   "ddt": "1313",
   "operator": "Dadas",
   "insertAt": "01/02/2021 12:15:47",
   "code": "R2021.001",
   "clientId": "cbaa9024-abf8-4575-8f44-c06bbb3d8a2e",
   "client": {
       "name": "AZM2E",
       "piva": "31137418148",
   }
   "@metadata": {
      "@collection": "repairOrders"
   }
}
```

I need to execute the query via REST API

Answer (score 3):

You can store a document from the `clients` collection as a **related document**
on a document from the `repairOrders` collection.

See example & walkthrough in **create-related-documents demo** 
https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/related-documents/create-related-documents

Then you can query collection `repairOrders`:

1. Include the related document in the query
2. Select/project the related document info in the query result
3. See example & walkthrough in **query-example demo** 
   https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/queries/query-example#step-6

To use `include` with **RQL** see:
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.1/csharp/indexes/querying/what-is-rql#include

Comment: the trick is to name the property as the collection? I'm using only HTTP API so that's important for me

Comment: I've tried also Graph API... WAW... this is good to me: match (repairOrders)-[clientId]->(clients as client)  is it OK for production?

Comment: The name for the property that holds/contains the **related document id** does Not have to be the same as the 'other' collection name